# How to disable angular 2 kendo-grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm looking for a way to disable an angular kendo-grid.

The user should not be able to add/edit/delete rows within the grid.

So, how to mark my kendo-gird as readonly, or disabled ?

I didn't find anything relevant in the [official documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/).

Comment: This may be relevant, I haven't used KendoUI with Angular specifically though. http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-grid---angularjs

Comment: @JayGould, Thanks for your comment Jay, but if you pay attention this is not for AngularJs

Answer (score 0):

In order to use binding you could bind to "att.disabled". Since it doesn't accept boolean values if you don't want it disabled you should return "null".

See the example bellow:
<kendo-grid [attr.disabled]="isDisabled == true ? true : null">